# Programmatically disable picture stabilization when taking a photo

Tags: android-camera

I have noticed on some phones that it takes quite a lot of time (sometimes even up to 10 seconds) from the moment `Camera.takePicture(null, null, JpegCallback)` is called to the moment `onPictureTaken` in picture callback is raised. Samsung Galaxy S5 seems to be the worst.

This happens when light conditions are bad and picture stabilization kicks in (http://www.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5-camera-tip-turn-picture-stabilization-unless-you-really-need-it). This picture stabilization takes extremely long time sometimes.

I was searching the internet on how to programmatically disable it, but I could only find the `setVideoStabilization()` method which handles video stabilization, not picture stabilization.

Does anyone know how to programmatically disable problematic picture stabilization before calling the `Camera.takePicture` method?